# Postman буду благодарен за помощь

Tags: javascript

У нас есть `postman` у нас есть 2 запроса:

1. Запросом я получаю данные с сервиса, `REST` который отдаёт данные в `json` формате.
2. Запрос отправляет эти данные с помощью `POST` на другой сервис.

**Вопрос:** второй запрос принимает данные не из результата первого, а отправляет данные с копипаста первого, можно ли избавиться от копипаста и автоматизировать передачу с одного источника в другой ?

Comment: Или подскажите какой тулзой можно это сделать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет ! Я делаю так как описано вот тут , думаю именно это Вы искали

1. Создаю `environment` и выбираю его
2. В самом `environment` - в стоке `key` - пишу имя (не важно какое, допустим "ТОКЕН") , столбец `values` не заполняю - в нем будет содержаться именно то , что мы хотим вытащить из запроса
3. В Запросе , в котором приходит json ответ с данными , для следующего запроса, мы ищем вкладку `test` и пишем в ней такой код:

   ```
   var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);   
   postman.setEnvironmentVariable("ТОКЕН", jsonData.token);
   ```
4. В предыдущем пункте мы сохранили значение token в наш environment . Теперь в новом/следующем нам осталось только начать вводить {{ как postman сам выдаст результат и предложит выбрать из environment наше значение .

В дальнейшем при выполнении первого запроса, в `environment` будут ложиться новые данные, так что запрос второй будет актуален и останется нажать SEND

Источник и наверное более подробное описание смотрите тут:

http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/